# How to use session in laravel 5.2 controller

Tags: session, laravel-5

I login and then keep the username in a session, then I refresh this page, but the session not keep value.

This is my code:

```php
class WelcomeCtrl extends Controller
{
     public function gotoWelcome()
     {   
         return view('welcome')->with('user',Session::get('user'));//nothing in session
     }

        public function dologin(){
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $result = "";
                if($username && $password){
                    $result = User::getUser($username, $password);
                    if($result){
                        Session::set('user',$result);
                        return response()->json([true, Session::get('user')]);//I get value expected, this is ok.
                    }
                }
                return response()->json([false, Session::get('user')]);     
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the middleware group 'web' to your routes. In 5.1 , this was default for all the routes and was used for session management and csrf verification etc.

Comment: Oh, I think I not added the middleware.

Comment: Keep in mind that recent versions of Laravel 5.2 now include the `web` middleware by default in the routing service provider, so no need to do this if you are running one of the new versions, such as 5.2.30.

Comment: I added the middleware like this:
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Route::post('dologin','WelcomeCtrl@dologin');
Route::get('gotoWelcome','WelcomeCtrl@gotoWelcome');
}

but when I login with $.post of jquery, it say:
"TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}...

am I miss something?

Comment: I put all controller in app\Http\controllers\ [all my file controller here]. is it ok with middleware => web

Answer (score 2):

If use want to use Session:: make sure you add session Facade by:

```
use Session;
```

Instead of this you can use session helper. So you can use below codes:

```
session()->user()->email;
session()->get('user');
session()->flash('message', 'Hi there.');
```

For more see [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-session).

Answer (score 0):

```
Session::put('key','value');//to put the session value
Session::get('key');//to get the session value

Session::has('key');//to check the session variable exist or not
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember one thing. When you post a form using ajax in Laravel 5.2, there will be a CsrfTokenMismatch error. To avoid this, add your route name which is accepting form values with ajax in your App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php in $except array. Then that route will accept form values with ajax request.

Comment: you can also send csrf token through ajax request @chipcoiga