# How do sessions work in Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am trying to understand how sessions work in Laravel 5(.4). 
In one hand there are two ways of using them as described in [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session):

> There are two primary ways of working with session data in Laravel: the global session helper and via a Request instance.

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

and

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

The documentation says:

> There is little practical difference between using the session via an HTTP request instance versus using the global session helper.

But it is never explained what the difference is.

In the other hand there is the "Facade way":

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

And recently I found this Stack Overflow question [How to use session in laravel 5.2 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952404/how-to-use-session-in-laravel-5-2-controller). [train_fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355822/train-fox) pointed out this way:

```
session()->put('key', 'value');
```

So that makes a total of four ways. And I cannot figure out why or when use one or another. Does someone know the difference between those four?

By the way, the only way I could get sessions to work with Redis was with the two last ways.

Thank you in advance for your enlightenment.

Comment: All are valid you can use anyone, regarding radius I haven't checked it. but all other works perfect. Some are Facad and some are helper functions to make life easier. `session()` is a helper function.

Comment: whatever way you choose it still just refers to the same session , when I mention session I mean the same session id and the same data which are associated with it. It doesn't really matter which one you use because it's still the same session. I use session helper because I found it more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider Facade first:

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

This facades calls `Illuminate\Session\Store::put()`.

Now let's consider the function `session()`:

```
function session($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return app('session');
    }

    if (is_array($key)) {
        return app('session')->put($key);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Reading this, we can assume that `session(['a' => 'b'])` works similar that `session()->put('a', 'b')` (because if it's an array, it calls `put` on the same function).

`app('session')` returns `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#facade-class-reference). `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager` has a `__call` function which in short calls the driver of the session. So it's the same behavior.

Now the difference may be in the `$request` function vs all other ones (as it's written in docs). According to the source code it returns a `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface`.  The `SessionInterface` has not the same methods as `Illuminate\Session\Store`so maybe it's why it differs.

Ok I give up. It's hard to understand. I can't help you more, I'm lost. I keep this post for history need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understood correctly `Session::put('key', 'value');`, `session()->put('key', 'value');` and `session(['key' => 'value']);
` work the same. Now there is still mystery around `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` for me.

Comment: Same problem for me. `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` is different and I don't understand why and what is different. That's why I gave up!

Comment: @louisfischer you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547684/difference-between-using-the-session-via-an-http-request-instance-versus-using-t